# Why we cannot mark the visibility of a class as "protected" in kotlin?

Tags: class, kotlin, visibility, protected, access-modifiers

I am new to kotlin I have been learning about inheritance in kotlin recently, and then I realised that we cannot mark the visibility of a class as "protected". Correct me if i am wrong, or is there any other way to make a class protected ?

Comment: I assume you mean for a top-level class. How would that even make sense? What does it mean to mark a class as protected?

Comment: Nested classes can be protected, exactly as in Java.

Comment: You should show a sample that has an issue with exact error, because what you are asking for *is* allowed so you must be doing something different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mark `protected` only parts of classes, so that they become accessible only from the derived classes. You can mark `protected` a member property, a member function or a nested class:

```
open class X {
    protected val v: SomeType = someValue
    protected fun f() { }
    protected class Y { ... }
}
```

But you cannot mark `protected` anything that does not belong to a class (e.g. a top-level class or function), because the modifier would make no sense: a top-level entity is not subject to inheritance, thus there can be no derived class that would access it.